# Does a DNS server exists for android?

Tags: dns, web-server

Is there a DNS server (named, bind) I could use to solve my problem ? Should I use other solution ?

I do not need all bunch of bind features, just setting A records and an easy mean to add/modify/delete those records would be perfect !

More explaination of the goal: I want to use android as mobile java web server (thanks to project like i-jetty) and in some rare case redirect the request of clients (connected through wifi / mixed client)
Right now this solution is embedded on a macbook air but I am looking for lighter solution.

Comment: Have you considered [searching in the playstore](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=dns+server&c=apps)? That would have answered your question immediately by just looking at the first 3 results.

Answer (score 1):

Just as Izzy suggested, I would recommend going to the play store. Here is what I found:

- [DNS Server](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.icecoldapps.dnsserver)

Thats really the only one available through the google play store. I haven't downloaded it for myself so I'm not vouching for it, but it might be worth a try.

Comment: This does not allow port 53.